# Generate unique random numbers to be stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code to check if the generated random number is available in the database. If the $smsCode is already in the database, then generate a new random number. But it is not working as expected.

```
$smsCode = 7552;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE sms_code = '$smsCode'";
        while($conn->query($query) === TRUE){
            $smsCode = rand(1000,9999);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE sms_code = '$smsCode'";
            $conn->query($query);
        }
$sql = "INSERT INTO appointment(number) VALUES('$smsCode');
```

`$smsCode = 7552` is already in the database but it keeps storing `7552` into the database instead of generating a new number to be stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$sms_code=rand(1000,9999);
$cond=True;
while($cond){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE sms_code = '$smsCode'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $sms_code=rand(1000,9999);
    }
    else
    {
        $cond=False;
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO appointment(number) VALUES('$smsCode')";
?>
```

Comment: This is NOT "race condition" safe.

Answer (score 1):

If the result of your first query returns a valid result it doesn't return `true`. The `query()` function only returns `false` if it fails, see [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php). So the condition of your while-loop where you make a comparison to the boolean `true` (cause of strict type comparions with three `=`) will never be true and so no new value is assigned to `$smsCode`.

Try something like this

```
$smsCode = 7552;

while(true) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE sms_code = '$smsCode'";
    if($conn->query($query) === false) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO appointment(number) VALUES('$smsCode')";
      break;
    } else {
      $smsCode = rand(1000,9999);
    }
}
```

This should generate a new code every time you don't have row in your database with that code.

Comment: You need to add `"` to the end of `$sql`

Comment: Ops didn't copied the whole query :O Thanks

Comment: You need to place it before `;`, but anyways, its more efficient than my code :)

Comment: A `do { ... } while ()` would be more sensible syntax.  BUT this approach is NOT "race condition" safe.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$date = date_create();
$smsCode = date_timestamp_get($date);
```

each time it will give you an unique random numbers